# How do i filter an array in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and have a situation where I am trying to set a state to a filtered version of another state(array). With the current code, each item in the unfiltered array is being changed to the filtering condition. How can I setFilteredJobs to only contain 'jobs', where status equals the status that the user has chosen in the AppPicker?

Here is my code:

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState()
const [filteredJobs, setFilteredJobs] = useState()
const [status, setStatus] = useState()


    const handleStatusChange = (item) => {
        setFilteredJobs(
            jobs.filter( job => job.status = item.label )
        )
        setStatus(item)
    }

return (
        <View style={defaultStyles.screenNoPadding}>
            <AppTextInput placeholder='Search for a Job' icon='magnify' />
            <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
                <AppPicker 
                    color='white'
                    selectedItem={category}
                    onSelectItem={item => handleCategoryChange(item)}
                    items={categories} 
                    placeholder='Filter' 
                    icon='apps' />
                <AppPicker 
                    color='white'
                    selectedItem={status}
                    onSelectItem={item => handleStatusChange(item)}
                    items={statuses} 
                    placeholder='Status' 
                    icon='apps' />
            </View>
            <FlatList 
                style={styles.list}
                data={filteredJobs ? filteredJobs : jobs}
                keyExtractor={job => job.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem 
                        company={item.company}
                        position={item.position}
                        status={item.status}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', { item })} 
                    /> 
                )} 
               ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator} 
            />
        </View>
    );
```

Thanks in advance! Keep in mind jobs is fetched in a useEffect on loading the component.

Comment: In the future it will help you if you log out the items with console.log before and after the filtering. The answer would have been more obvious if you had done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you should use a comparison, and not an attribuition.

```
    const handleStatusChange = (item) => {
        setFilteredJobs(
                                        // FIX HERE, USE == INSTEAD OF =
            jobs.filter( job => job.status == item.label )
        )
        setStatus(item)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that before but I guess I didn't do it right!

Answer (score 1):

@guilherme is right, it's a simple mistake, you assigned instead of comparing. Get in the habit of using `===` to compare strings.

Also the way to tackle these problems in the future: `console.log` before and after the thing you are doing that isn't working. It would have jumped out at you pretty quick if you had. Use `JSON.stringify` for logging of objects if you are getting `[Object object]` in the logging output.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter